# Extract url's with rvest - returns {{article.Link}} instead of the link?

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse, rvest

I am trying to scrape the url's from the website "https://politi.dk/doegnrapporter". I use rvest and dplyr in R, but my code outputs `{{article.Link}}` instead of the actual link. I think this has to do with some Java script in the html-code of the website loading the website of the link, but how do I counteract this when scraping the url's in R.
My code so far is:

```
library(rvest)

page <- read_html("https://politi.dk/doegnrapporter")
t <- page %>% html_nodes("a.newsResultLink") %>% html_attr('href')
t
[1] "{{article.Link}}"
```

So instead of `{{article.Link}}` I want a list of the url's of the hyperlinks e.g. "https://politi.dk/oestjyllands-politi/doegnrapporter/doegnrapport07092021/2021/09/07", "https://politi.dk/nordsjaellands-politi/doegnrapporter/nordsjaellands-politi-uddrag-af-doegnrapport-0607-september-2021/2021/09/07" etc.

Comment: What do you want to extract exactly?

Comment: The url's from the css element (i.e. the. hyperlinks of the website).

Comment: In order to gather a list of url's of all the articles the website is referring to.

Comment: That web page uses the Angular javascript library. Packages like `rvest` cannot run javascript code. If you need to scrape such a page, you'll need to use a package like RSelenium to use a web browser which can run javascript to get the data,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is pulled from an `ng-init` attribute of an element with class `newsList`. This is associated with `ngInit` directive in Angular, whereby that data is loaded dynamically to where you see in on the webpage when JavaScript runs on the page.

You can extract the content from that attribute, regex out the appropriate JavaScript object to handle as json, then extract the links from within that:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)

page <- read_html('https://politi.dk/doegnrapporter')
m <- page |> html_element('.newsList') |> html_attr('ng-init') |> str_match(., 'init\\((.*)\\)')
data <- jsonlite::parse_json(m[2])
articles <- lapply(data$AllNews$NewsList, function(x) x$Link) |> unlist(recursive = F)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @QHarr. It worked with some modifications. 1) I used `%>%` instead of `|>`. And `html_element()` does not seem to be in the version of rvest I use, so I substituted it with `html_node()` and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome. Yes, you made the right changes. For 1) See [this](https://michaelbarrowman.co.uk/post/the-new-base-pipe/) and 2) See [this](https://rvest.tidyverse.org/reference/html_element.html). There are some definite advantages to upgrading rvest at least.